# Public access outside of package only through interface creating instance by factory

Tags: java

Is it a good design or wrong? Dao class isn't accessed outside the package. It is created only within package access modifier. All access only through interface.

```
public interface IDao {

    void perform();

}


//package access
class Dao implements IDao{

    private Dao(){}

    @Override
    void perform(){...}

    Dao getInstance(){
        ...
        return new Dao();
    }

}

//in the same package as Dao
public class DaoFactory{

    private DaoFactory(){}

    public static IDao createDao(){
        return Dao.getInstance();
    }
}
```

Creating and invoking:

```
IDao dao = DaoFactory.createDao();
dao.perform();
```

Comment: Whether or not this is a good design is largely dependent on what the problem is that you're trying to solve.  Can you provide some context about what it is you're trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to provide an interface to external connection and want to encapsulate it in the way as i described above.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood you correctly.

In short, using interface instead of classes (implementation) is always good because client code doesn't depend on implementation which can be easily changed. No matter if client code located in same package or anywhere else. It's loose coupling, it's D in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).